# How do I get my local Maven to overwrite an existing artefact that was overwritten in my network repository

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have a Maven repository folder on our network drive, which contains all the artefacts we use.

Everyone in the office uses a standard settings.xml file on their local Maven setup which contains the location of that network drive as a remote repository.

In this way, we keep the network Maven repository folder updated so the local environment on everyone's computers simply downloads from that central repository folder, which avoids re-downloading off the internet for everyone.

We are busy developing a new library, lets say "MyLib 1.0.0".  We install it into the central network maven folder repository, and everyone's local Maven projects use that dependency in their project(s). But now, we have not officially released "MyLib 1.0.0", its still a work in progress, so once we make further updates to it, we overwrite the "MyLib 1.0.0" artefact in the central repository.

Problem is, because all our local Maven's have already downloaded the artefact into their local Maven repositories, they wont re-download it. It already exists.  I don't want to increase the version of "MyLib" yet because its not an official release, and I also don't want everyone to have to change their dependency version in their pom.xml files. I just want to replace the "MyLib 1.0.0" file and have everyone's local Maven's download and overwrite their local copy automatically. (At the moment everyone has to be told to go and remove the artefact from their local Maven repository manually, as which point it will re-download the latest copy of "MyLib 1.0.0")

What is best practice for the above, or how can I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description there are comming two things into my mind.

First: 
  Stop using a network drive. Better start using a repository manager.
  Apart from that a network drive is dammed slow.

Second:

In Maven a release is immutable which means if you have version 1.0 and deploy to your repository it will never being changed anymore. If you need to make a change on that you have to use a different version for example 1.0.1 etc.

You should start using SNAPSHOT's instead of releases if you are developing which is exactly causing the problem:

> At the moment everyone has to be told to go and remove the artefact
>   from their local Maven repository manually, as which point it will
>   re-download the latest copy of "MyLib 1.0.0"

Which shows you are working against the concepts of Maven.

And third. It sounds like you don't use a continious integration for your builds.

Comment: I do use SNAPSHOT, but the other developers computers don't overwrite their local maven copy from the network drive automatically. I still have to tell them to delete their local copy. Any ideas why?

Comment: You did wrote different. Furthermore i would suggest to setup a repository manager and they can control it via `mvn -U ` usage etc.